# how to do a horizontal carousel layout in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-vue

[image]

As the picture above demonstrates, I want a layout that could contain A,B,C 3 sections. But only section B would be visible, A & C should be hidden, but when user swipe on section B, they could see the content of section A or C. I know ScrollView could do this, but I don't want it to be scrollable to the user. I want to programmatically control the behaviour when user swipes on it. Similar to the carousel. I have tried normal layout like GridLayout, FlexboxLayout...they all will contain the elements in the page, they just didnt let them overflow. So anyone has any idea on how to work around on it, please let me know, thanks.

Comment: you can use `radlistview` for this purpose. it provides swipe events. with the help of that you can show only the layout which you want.

Comment: Create a playground sample and show some work here. So that people have a look at it and resolve the issue. your question has no weightage

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using nativescript-carousel (https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-carousel) to achieve this. I think that is pretty much what you are after - just hide the indicator (dots). There are demos on that page for how to use with vanilla javascript, angular, or vue.

It makes use of `DKCarouselView` for iOS and `ViewPager` for Android.

You can also hook onto the slide tap and change events easily enough, which is all in the demo usage instructions.

Comment: thanks, it could solve my problem for now, but I am still curious about how to do a horizontal overflowed layout without these plugins.